# Delete a record from another form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship that consist of 3 tables:

1. Server(ServerSKU(pk))
2. HDD (HDDSKU(pk))
3. HDD-Server (ServerSKU(pk), HDDSKU(pk)

I also have 2 forms:

1. frmItem (Display items)
2. frmEdit (Edit/Delete items)

On frmItem, this is where you see thousands of items and when you click the btnEdit, it will take you to frmEdit. On frmEdit, you can choose to update or delete the item. What I am trying to achieve is when I update the item I would like to delete the previous information that was entered for that item. For example:

- txtHDD: HDD1
- txtServer: Server1

If I change txtHDD to HDD2, I would like for the name of that item to be updated to HDD2 and delete the HDD1 from the table "Server."

The following code is able to update the record but it does not delete HDD1 in the table "Server".

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [HDD] ([HDDSKU])" _
& "VALUES(" _
& "'" & Me!txtHDD & "') "

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [HDD-Server] SET HDDSKU = '" & Me!txtHDD  & "' WHERE ServerSKU = '" & Me!txtServer & "'"
```

I also attempted to use this following code but I couldn't get it to work:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM [HDD] WHERE HDDSKU = '" & Forms![frmItem]!txtHDD & "'"
```

Comment: So you're not really updating the record, you're creating an entirely new one? Why delete the old record, just mark it as inactive.  You don't ever need to refer to the values for historical report?  "INSERT INTO" does not update a record. Please be very clear on what you are trying to do. Also, using text as a primary key is often frowned upon. The most commonly accepted method is to use AutoNumber for primary key. Furthermore, changing your primary key in a record is a really bad idea.  If there are other tables that use foriegn keys of that primary, you've just created orphan records.

Comment: I am but since I have a M:N relationship if I update txtHDD I would have to update the HDDSKU on both the tables "HDD" & "HDD-Server." I was able to use the UPDATE statement in table "HDD-Server" but I can't seem to figure out how to do that with the table "HDD." Is there a way to update the table "HDD" using the UPDATE statement? Thanks for the primary key tip!

Comment: what is the recordsource for frmEdit?

Comment: If you were using an autonumber for you primary key in HDD and just included a descrip field for "HDD1" or "HDD2", then you wouldn't have to change the value in both of your tables. Only one table. Your server table would still have the primary key from HDD so that you could reference the new description anytime you wanted.  This is one of the main concepts of a relational database.  You're heading down a very slippery road. I would strongly recommend changing your table structure so that you only have to change the value in one place.

Comment: frmEdit is just a form with the textboxes where I copy it over from frmItem. I see what is happening. Thank you for letting me know. So it is always bad to have just one column in a table for this situation, am I correct?

Comment: It's bad to copy data between multiple tables. You're actual data should only be in one table. Then you use primary keys and foreign keys to relate that data to each other. Since the keys should never change, when you change a piece of data in one table, all tables linked to it will see the same change.